# Java How how do I print a statement 1000 times with least amount of lines

Tags: java

I recently started with coding with java so I have a really limited knowledge of coding. I want to know how to print a line such as "Bob ate a burger" 1000 times with the least amount of lines. IMPORTANT: I can't use loops(such as "for" or "while"), but I MUST use methods.
Factorials of 1000:1,2,4,5,8,10,20,25,40,50,100,125,200,250,500,1000
The least I have gotten was about 37 lines: (I know that this is clearly not even close to the least) Thank You so much.

```
public class Random{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        twofifty();
        twofifty();
        twofifty();
        twofifty();    
    }
    public static void fives(){
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
    }
    public static void fifty()
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
        fives();
    }
    public static void twofifty(){
        fifty();
        fifty();
        fifty();
        fifty();
        fifty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use recursion? That would be using a method without loops.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm actually a newbie so I have no clue how to use that.

Comment: Hint: factorize 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion, i.e. call your method recursively and maintain a counter which when reaches 1000, terminate the recursion.

```
public class Recusrion{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   print(0);
  }
  static void print(int num){
    if (num > 1000)
      return;
    System.out.println(num);
    print(++num);
 }
}
```

Comment: It is better to provide your answer in a more descriptive way along with example for newbie's better understanding. Otherwise, write this as a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other's can golf this answer. It is designed to "use methods". Not sure if `foreach` counts as a loop. Sort of depends on one's definition. Methods are assumed to exist in a class `RecursePrint`, so adjust as needed.

```
public void out(int cntr) {
    System.out.println("Bob's your uncle (" + cntr + ")");
}
```

This method uses the IntStream, and a `foreach`. Again, not sure if `foreach` violates loop idea.

```
public void oneLiner()
{
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).forEach(i -> out(i));
}
```

Recursion approach (primitive). In this case, the method calls itself until it reaches the desired count. It could be changed to take a parameter of the maximum. It uses an `if` statement, but no loops.

```
public void doit(int cntr)
{
    if (cntr >= 1000) {
        return;
    }

    out(cntr);
    doit(++cntr);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RecursePrint rp = new RecursePrint();
    rp.doit(0);
    rp.oneLiner();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assume time > 0 
private static void printLine(int time) {
    if(time != 0) {
        System.out.println("bob doing something");
        printLine(time-1);
    }
}
```

And call it like `printLine(1000);`

Comment: @Noob1029 FYI you can visit [this article](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java) to understand more about recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion! If you call the print function with an argument of 1000, this will print "Bob ate a burger" 1000 times.

```
public class Hello {

public static void print(int count) {
    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Bob ate a burger");
        print(count-1);
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    print(1000);

}
```

}

Since you are new to coding, let me walk you through this code. Basically this is a recursive function which means the function calls itself over and over again until it reaches a base case. In our case, the base case is that if the number of times we want to print "Bob ate a burger" is 0, we will just return from the function so the function won't do anything. This function's return type is void so it doesn't return anything. Also base case is needed because the function needs to know when to stop or it will keep going forever.

By passing in count = 1000, the print function will first check if count is 0. It is not so it will print the string "Bob ate a burger" one time. Then it will call that function again but this time with a count of 999. So now since count is not 0, it will print that string again.

The function will keep doing this until count is 0 and then we just exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream`:

```
public static void print(int times) {
    IntStream.range(0, times).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Bob ate burgers"));
}

print(1000);    // this is client code
```

You can use recursion, but problem is for big `times` you could get `SacOverflowException:`

```
public static void print(int times) {
    if (times >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        print2(--times);
    }
}

print(1000);    // this is client code
```

Next variant use two different method, to emulate call stack without recursion:

```
public static void print(int times) {
    step1(times, 0);
}

private static void step1(int times, int i) {
    step2(times, i);
}

private static void step2(int times, int i) {
    if (i < times) {
        System.out.println("Bob ate burgers");
        step1(times, ++i);
    }
}

print(1000);    // this is client code
```